# How important is image mean subtraction in convnets?

Tags: tensorflow, neural-network, deep-learning, conv-neural-network

So I've read that mean subtraction is very important for images since it zero-centers the data.
From [this](http://cs231n.github.io/neural-networks-2/) lecture.

> However, it is very important to zero-center the data, and it is common to see normalization of every pixel as well.

Yet I've never seen this in practice in all the MNIST and cat/dog classification tutorials out there. Is it really that important? What would happen if you did not zero-center the data? Can anyone point to me a tutorial notebook, preferably in Tensorflow, that shows mean subtraction being done?

Answer (score 1):

Input normalization, in particular mean subtraction, is indeed an important preprocessing step that is often necessary in practice to make the SGD converge.

You are mistaken when you state that it is barely used in tutorials: it is present almost everywhere. For example, tensorflow's CIFAR-10 tutorial normalize images [here](https://github.com/tensorflow/models/blob/master/tutorials/image/cifar10/cifar10_input.py#L186).

The only common exception is MNIST and it is unfortunate that it is also the omnipresent CNN-101 tutorial, perhaps leaving a lasting impression that image normalization is optional after all.

I made a small experiment with tensorflow's [deep MNIST tutorial](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/r1.2/tensorflow/examples/tutorials/mnist/mnist_deep.py) by comparing results with and without normalization.

The standard implementation produces:

```
step 0, training accuracy 0.1
step 100, training accuracy 0.94
step 200, training accuracy 0.88
step 300, training accuracy 0.9
step 400, training accuracy 0.92
step 500, training accuracy 0.92
step 600, training accuracy 0.92
step 700, training accuracy 0.98
step 800, training accuracy 0.98
step 900, training accuracy 0.9
step 1000, training accuracy 0.94
step 1100, training accuracy 0.98
step 1200, training accuracy 0.96
step 1300, training accuracy 0.94
step 1400, training accuracy 0.98
step 1500, training accuracy 1
step 1600, training accuracy 0.94
step 1700, training accuracy 0.96
step 1800, training accuracy 1
step 1900, training accuracy 0.96
test accuracy 0.974
```

When adding normalization

```
x_image = tf.map_fn(lambda frame: tf.image.per_image_standardization(frame), x_image)
```

I obtained

```
step 0, training accuracy 0.1
step 100, training accuracy 0.86
step 200, training accuracy 0.92
step 300, training accuracy 0.86
step 400, training accuracy 0.94
step 500, training accuracy 0.98
step 600, training accuracy 0.94
step 700, training accuracy 0.96
step 800, training accuracy 1
step 900, training accuracy 0.92
step 1000, training accuracy 0.92
step 1100, training accuracy 0.98
step 1200, training accuracy 0.98
step 1300, training accuracy 0.96
step 1400, training accuracy 0.96
step 1500, training accuracy 1
step 1600, training accuracy 0.98
step 1700, training accuracy 0.96
step 1800, training accuracy 0.94
step 1900, training accuracy 1
test accuracy 0.974
```

In the end I got the exact (!) same test accuracy after 2000 step in both cases. So image normalization does not degrade performance here, but does not add much.

The real question is, what makes the MNIST dataset so special that it does not benefit from image normalization. It could be due to the nature of the images, which are mostly constant, or to the nets usually used on this dataset (LeNet and variants) that are shallow enough to be able to cope with non-zero mean data.